# Trying to use markushi circlebutton, nothing appears on the screen?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use markushi circlebutton in my android project in eclipse. No error message, just does not show the button on the screen, help me please, Thank you!

Here's the MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.test2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private at.markushi.ui.CircleButton m_circleButton;


boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent goto_next_activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(goto_next_activity);
        }
    });

    m_circleButton = (at.markushi.ui.CircleButton) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
    m_circleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent goto_third_activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(goto_third_activity);
            }


    } );

}


}
```

and activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test2">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#3b5998"
    android:text="Go2"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cb_color="#ff99cc"
    app:cb_pressedRingWidth="5dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:background="#3b5998"
    android:text="Go3"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set **android:layout_width and android:layout_height** with same value

```
 <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cb_color="#ff99cc"
    app:cb_pressedRingWidth="5dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:background="#3b5998"
    android:text="Go3"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Thanks Amiya, It helped me. But now I cant put my text on the button as "android:text = "Go3" doesn't  work!

Comment: @EhsanJkr First of all use this android:layout_below="@id/button1" (remove+ sign)

Comment: android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"

Comment: @EhsanJkr Can you upload your circle button image

Comment: @Amiya thank you, sorry don't know how to upload but its just a circle button with no text or any other thing on it, but when I click it works and can go to another activity, just don't know how to put a drawable or text on it!

Comment: @Amiya, I think it just works with "android:src" and drawables and not working with texts!

Comment: If you see inside the source, the CircularButton extends ImageView, can change it to extends Button and remove the setScaleType line and you are good to go. CircularButton with text..